# How to check if a given directory exists in Ruby

Tags: ruby, directory

I am trying to write a script which automatically checks out or updates a Subversion URL based on whether a specified directory exists or not.

For some reason, my code isn't working and always returns *true* even if it's false:

```
def directory_exists?(directory)
  return false if Dir[directory] == nil
  true
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

If it matters whether the file you're looking for is a *directory* and not just a file, you could use `File.directory?` or `Dir.exist?`. This will return true only if the file exists and is a directory.

As an aside, a more idiomatic way to write the method would be to take advantage of the fact that Ruby automatically returns the result of the last expression inside the method. Thus, you could write it like this:

```
def directory_exists?(directory)
  File.directory?(directory)
end
```

Note that using a method is not necessary in the present case.

Comment: Why bother even putting it inside another method? Just call it directly!

Comment: @Radar I figured that the stripped-down method was likely simplified for the purpose of the question and that the actual method might contain some additional logic. If no other logic needs to go in the method, I agree. By all means, just run directory? directly.

Comment: Wouldn't `Dir.exists?` not be cleaner than `File.directory?`?

Comment: `Dir.exists?` is deprecated, use `Dir.exist`

Comment: @burningpony my bad, it's `Dir.exist?`

Answer (score 52):

You can also use [`Dir::exist?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-exist-3F) like so:

```
Dir.exist?('Directory Name')
```

> Returns `true` if the 'Directory Name' is a directory, `false` otherwise.<sup>[1](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-exist-3F)</sup>

Answer (score 48):

All the other answers are correct, however, you might have problems if you're trying to check directory in a user's home directory. Make sure you expand the relative path before checking:

```
File.exists? '~/exists'
=> false
File.directory? '~/exists'
=> false
File.exists? File.expand_path('~/exists')
=> true
```

Answer (score 19):

```
File.exist?("directory")
```

`Dir[]` returns an array, so it will never be `nil`. If you want to do it your way, you could do

```
Dir["directory"].empty?
```

which will return `true` if it *wasn't* found.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Kernel#test`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-test):

```
test ?d, 'some directory'
```

it gets it's origins from https://ss64.com/bash/test.html
you will notice bash `test` has this flag `-d` to test if a directory exists
`-d file      True if file is a Directory. [[ -d demofile ]]`

Comment: This is neat. Not the most immediately _expressive_, but neat.