# ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate at /template_name

Tags: ruby, conditional-operator, partials, rails7

I need to dynamically load a sidebar's content into a sidebar partial based on the presence of a directory name-spaced as the `controller_name` (if present) and the `action_name` (always used).  They both are derived from the Rails hash and map to the `.../views/sidebars/[controller_name]/[action_name]` if there is a directory for the `controller_name` and to `.../views/sidebars/[action_name]` if there isn't an associated directory namespaced with the Controller's name.

```
/views
  /sidebars
    /static
      /_about.html.erb
      /_contact.html.erb
      /...
    /_styles.html.erb  #outside of any controller structure
```

I am trying to use the following code to dynamically load the correct sidebar partial:

`<%= "sidebars/#{controller_name}".to_s.present? ?  yield("sidebars/#{controller_name}/#{action_name}" : yield("sidebars/#{action_name}") %>`

This checks to see if there is a directory called by the `controller_name` and it renders the correct partial based on the structure indicated.

I am getting the following error:

```
Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check   <div id='sidebar_left'>
    <p>Template: [_sidebar-left.html.erb]</p>
    <%= render "sidebars/#{action_name}" %>
    <%= "sidebars/#{controller_name}".to_s.present? ?  yield("sidebars/#{controller_name}/#{action_name}" : yield("sidebars/#{action_name}") %>
```

***UPDATE***

Ok so it turns out that ternary operators don't always return the value, particularly if it is a computed string value.  In this case, I was expecting the value to return as either `sidebars/static/home` or `sidebars/styles`.  For some reason I can't explain, ternary operators don't work that way, even though I (thought!) I was returning a string value from the operation.

To get rid of the syntax error, I had to assign the operator to a variable name, in this case `sb_name` and then render it on the next line.  This is the final code:

```
<% sb_name = "sidebars/#{controller_name}".to_s.present? ? "sidebars/#{controller_name}/#{action_name}" : "sidebars/#{action_name}" %>
<%= render sb_name %>
```

Now, while this resolved the syntax error, I am now getting a `Missing partial sidebars/_about`  error in the view.  The `_styles` file exists as `/views/sidebars/_styles.html.erb`, right where it should.  Since there is not a folder name-spaced to the controller being called (in this case `StylesController`), it should be pulling up the file directly underneath the `/sidebars/` directory.  However, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some help on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085218/how-to-check-if-a-given-directory-exists-in-ruby).  I wasn't checking the directory/file structure properly.  The final syntax is this:

```
<% sb_name = File.directory?("app/views/sidebars/#{controller_name}") ? "/sidebars/#{controller_name}/#{action_name}" : "/sidebars/#{action_name}" %>
<%= render partial: "#{sb_name}" %>
```